# What exactly is this code doing?

Tags: shell, unix

Could anyone tell me what this piece of code is doing?

```
            usage()
            {
                 echo "Usage: $0 -p ";
                 echo " p - process id ";
                 exit 1;
            }
```

I am a unix novice so just trying to piece together example scripts to get a grasp.

Answer (score 2):

It is a shell function called `usage()`.  It reports how the program (script) is supposed to be used and exits.

Apparently, you should type:

```
$ script -1234
```

to work on process 1234.  If you misused the script, it would replace `$0` with the script name:

```
Usage: script -p
 p - process id
```

It should be reporting usage to standard error:

```
echo "Usage: $0 -p" >&2
echo " p - process id" >&2
```

The semicolons are superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

`usage` is a function. When called, it prints:

```
Usage: $0 -p
p - process id
```

Where `$0` is set to the name of the file.

And finally exits.

This is a typical function created to show users how to use a specific command. It is called whenever the number of parameters is not correct / the parameters given are incorrect.

In this specific case, it explains that the script has to be executed with `-p` parameter.